# Whats the core difference between Kies, New PC Studio, PC Studio 3.1 from Samsung?

Tags: samsung-kies, windows, pc-studio

The web site doesn't specifically say...but I assume that Kies is for Android based devices, NPS and PCStudio are for W7p and other Phone OSs?

Comment: Kies is also for Bada based systems - maybe even primarly, because the built in "Samsung Apps" store only carries Bada apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New PC Studio is for Samsung's proprietary OS<sup>[1](http://www.widgetslab.com/2008/09/29/samsung-pixon-m8800-reviewed-comes-with-touchwiz-and-18-widgets/)</sup>.  I believe PC Studio 3.1 is just an older or region-specific version of NPS.

RoToRa is correct that Kies is for both Bada and Android.  It appears they are transitioning to using "Kies Mini" for Android, which is really just a means of updating the device software.  Media management, sync, etc. is intended to be done through the "cloud" on Android devices.

After looking at the Samsing website, I believe they do not have management software for their Windows Phone 7 devices.