# Which one is more suitable Samsung Kies or PC Studio for Samsung GT-B7722?

Tags: samsung-kies, pc-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the core difference between Kies, New PC Studio, PC Studio 3.1 from Samsung?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7030/whats-the-core-difference-between-kies-new-pc-studio-pc-studio-3-1-from-samsun)

I purchased SAmsungGT-B7722. I want to connect it with PC for internet, Contact swapping and other uses. Please advise which software is better SAMSUNG KIES or SAMSUNG PC STUDIO. Samsung offers for free download of both on its site

Answer (score 3):

According to the Download Center, Samsung PC Studio does not support Android Phones (though I did not try using that), and it directly points to download Samsung Kies.
Also, Samsung Kies - as far as I can say - is easier to use, with ability to connect to the device via WiFi as well. Therefore, I would recommend using Samsung Kies.